# Manhwa with a girl who dies and is reincarnated in the past

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

So I've been looking for this manhwa that I have not finished and I can't stop thinking about it. Here's all I can remember: it starts off with this orphan girl who is poor and works at a convenience store. She ends up dying somehow and is reincarnated back to a prior time in history with concubines and stuff. She wakes up seeing this hot guy who seems to be her friend. He has white hair and is wearing blue. She can't read the writing because she is in the past. And later on in the story she ends up being exiled from the place.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. What colour was the female lead's hair? Also, can you tell us a bit more about the person she was reincarnated as? Was she a princess? A noble? And why was she exiled?

Comment: When she was reincarnated she had blackish brownish hair. She was reincarnated as like a village girl but I think she might’ve been a concubine. And the reason she was exiled was because I think someone set her up to make it look like she was having an affair since she was a concubine. I’m not rlly sure how it works tho. I do know that she wasn’t interested in the emperor but someone else.

Answer (score 2):

This is *[Ellin's Solhwa](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/ellins-solhwa)*.

> The last thing Ellin remembers is having to deal with a belligerent customer at her dead-end job. And when she opened her eyes… she’s “Solhwa,” the beautiful fourth concubine to the king of the Xyaran Empire. Between **trying to learn the language** and eating steak, Ellin’s trying to figure exactly what’s going on. Where is she? How did this happen? And who can she trust: Solhwa’s handsome charismatic childhood friend or the elegant, raven-haired king’s advisor?

[image: Convenience store]

The story opens with Ellin working at a convenience store, dealing with an irate customer. Her parents are dead; her mom died of a disease that Ellin inherited, and she dies shortly after. She reincarnates as a concubine, in training to potentially become queen, but doesn't remember anything about her new body and can't read or write.

The first thing she sees when she wakes up is her childhood friend, with silver hair

[image: waking up]

She does eventually get into trouble due to her perceived closeness to the king's advisor (as mentioned in the synopsis).